# In angular select there is an empty line in ng-options while ng-model is ok?

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I've got an issue with ng-options and select while I have an array that give the options and an ng-model well given : if I delete some line in the array, even if the value of the ng-model is still in it, angular add an extra empty slot in the list.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lyxthe/8rqbvc1n/25/) to see the issue.

- look at the droplist, not any empty slot, click the button, one line is delete, an empty slot appears,
- click the button a second time, one line is delete, the empty slot remains, but not any new ones

when you arrive at 1 only value in the list, the button will make new lines, and the empty line goes away.

if you first select another value than 5 every thing is fine.
the version of angular I use is the 1.2.26, I've seen in  1.1.5 that there is no issue... don't know where it changes.

the html :

```
    <body ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <button ng-click="changeoptions()"  ng-disabled="obj.disabled">change options length</button>
        <select ng-options="value for value in obj.options" ng-model="obj.model" ng-change="updateDisabled()">    </select> : model={{obj.model}}, options={{obj.options}}, options.length={{obj.options.length}}.
    </body>
```

the js :

```
 function Ctrl($scope){
        $scope.test=true;
        $scope.obj={};
        $scope.obj.options=[1,2,3,4,5];
        $scope.obj.model=$scope.obj.options[4];
        $scope.obj.disabled=false;
        $scope.updateDisabled=function(){
            if(!$scope.obj.model){
                $scope.obj.model=$scope.obj.options[0];
            }
            $scope.obj.disabled=$scope.obj.model==1;
        }
        $scope.changeoptions=function(){
            var length=$scope.obj.options.length;                       
            $scope.obj.options=[];
            if($scope.test){                                
                for(var i=0;i<length-1;i++){
                    $scope.obj.options[i]=5-(length-2-i);
                }
                if($scope.obj.options[0]==$scope.obj.model){
                    $scope.test=false;
                }
            }else{                          
                for(var i=0;i<length+1;i++){
                    $scope.obj.options[i]=5-(length-i);
                }   
                if($scope.obj.options[0]==1){
                    $scope.test=true;
                }
            }                   
        }                           
    }
```

Have you an explanation for this behavior ?

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

This must be an issue in the Angular 1.2 branch.

By changing to the latest Angular 1.3 version, I was [able to get it working](http://jsfiddle.net/4u7odcqp/). Note that I had to swap to using the `.controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl($scope,...) {` syntax instead to get it to work.